# Using OR operator in React js conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to conditionally render a button based on two conditions.
Am not really sure if am doing it the right way.

But i get this error ***This condition will always return 'true' since the types '"started"' and '"cancelled"' have no overlap.ts(2367)*** where the red underline is.

Am using **React js with typescript**
[image]

Comment: So when do you want to show the button?

Comment: This has nothing to do with React, it's a simple logic error. Your condition will always be true, since `journey` will *always* be different from either "started" or "cancelled", no matter which value it actually has. You probably want to replace that `||` with another `&&`

Comment: when journey !== "started" and journey !== "cancelled" is true, because it has about three states (started, cancelled and stopped)

Answer (score 2):

When you are checking for multiple values, you can simplify with `includes` method

```
{ !["started", "cancelled"].includes(journey) && <Button> Cancel Journey </Button> }
```

Alternatively

```
{ journey === "stopped" && <Button> Cancel Journey </Button> }
```

or

```
{ ["stopped"].includes(journey) && <Button> Cancel Journey </Button> }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error. A variable can not have two values at the same time which means that `journey !== "started" || journey !== "cancelled"` will always be true.

You probably want to use `journey === "started"` in order to display the Cancel Button

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two options in your condition like "stared" and "cancelled" you can add ternary operator.

```
{journey === "stared" ? <Button>Journey Started</Button> : <Button>Journey Cancelled </Button>}
```

But if more options like ("stared","cancelled","completed","any other")

```
  {journey === "stared" && <Button>Journey Started</Button> }
  {journey === "cancelled" && <Button>Journey cancelled</Button> }
  {journey === "completed" && <Button>Journey completed</Button> }
```

This is an optional thing, It's a best practice not to use strings directly in conditions. Better you define them as type, or enum,(If using typescript with React) or just costs;

```
const STARTED = "started"
const COMPLETED = "completed"
const CANCELED = "canceld"

const journey = STARTED // Or anything the matches with the requirement.


{journey === STARTED ? <Button>Journey Started</Button> : <Button>Journey Cancelled </Button>}
```